# Socket Programming C# Chat server, Cross thread in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, async-await

I try to create simple chat server, which handle multiple clients, and recives messages from all of them. 
Below is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ChatServer
{

    public interface IServerPresenter
    {
        void Start(IServerView view);
        void StartServer(string address, int port);
        void CloseServer();

    }
    public class ServerPresenter : IServerPresenter
    {
        public IServerView ServerView { get; set; }

        private TcpListener Server;

        public void CloseServer()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Start(IServerView view)
        {
            ServerView = view;
        }

        public void StartServer(string address, int port)
        {
            try
            {
                Server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(address), port);
                Server.Start();
                ServerView.UpdateChatBox("Server is started, waiting for clients...");
                ListenForClientsAsync();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ServerView.UpdateChatBox(e.Message);
            }
        }

        private async void ListenForClientsAsync()
        {

            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    var client = await Server.AcceptTcpClientAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    if (client.Connected)
                    {
                        ReadStreamAsync(client);
                        ServerView.UpdateChatBox("Client connected.");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ServerView.UpdateChatBox(e.Message);
            }
        }

        private async void ReadStreamAsync(TcpClient client)
        {
            NetworkStream streamer = client.GetStream();

            Byte[] buff = new Byte[1024];
            String msg;

            int buffRecived = await streamer.ReadAsync(buff, 0, buff.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
            msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buff);

            if (buffRecived > 0)
                ServerView.UpdateChatBox(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

So If I don't use windows form but Commandline Version everything seems to be fine, multiple clients can connect to socket and send messages.

But If I'm using Windows Forms version (included code)  it recives cross thread exception. I think the problem is

```
var client = await Server.AcceptTcpClientAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

and

```
int buffRecived = await streamer.ReadAsync(buff ,0 , buff.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

becouse if I remove ConfigureAwait(false), looks to be fine but....program doesn't work correctly, becouse If client connect and send a message, the program waits for another connection, and don't recive messages from connected client. Anyone have idea how I can change it to work correctly?

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ChatServer
{

    public interface IServerView
    {
        void UpdateChatBox(string message);
        void UpdateClientBox(string message);
    };
    public partial class ServerView : Form, IServerView
    {

        private IServerPresenter _presenter;
        public ServerView(IServerPresenter presenter)
        {
            _presenter = presenter;

            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public void UpdateChatBox(string message)
        {
            chatListBox.Items.Add(message);
        }

        public void UpdateClientBox(string message)
        {
            clientListBox.Items.Add(message);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _presenter.StartServer(textBox1.Text, Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The simplest change would probably be to use IsInvokeRequired in before accessing the UI controls in the view. See [Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx). Note that you don't have to define a new delegate type, you can just use the built-in `Action<string>` type.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: it is not true that `ListenForClientsAsync()` runs synchronously. Any `async` method with an `await` statement will return on reaching the `await` statement. The remainder of the method will execute asynchronously.

Comment: You're absolutely right... I missed that on account I was caught up in the method itself not being awaited

Comment: @mikez: I disagree that there's any need to use `IsInvokeRequired`. Even in legacy code, this was never really necessary (just invoke unconditionally), but the modern C# idiom does away with explicit invoking altogether, and thus there certainly is no need to check that property. Using `async`/`await` allows the compiler and runtime deal with all of the real work.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Sure not totally necessary it really just saves you a few extra allocations for the pieces needed to do the invoke in the scenario where you are already on the UI thread. It could also be done via `Progress<T>` which automatically marshals back to the UI thread (assuming it was created there).

Comment: @mike: _"it really just saves you a few extra allocations for the pieces needed to do the invoke in the scenario where you are already on the UI thread"_ -- in practice, one pretty much _never_ has code that would check `IsInvokeRequired` unless the first time it's checked it will always return `true`. It's used only as a trigger to allow the method to be re-entrant cross-thread. So there's no real savings, and in fact there's extra overhead, because `Control.Invoke()` effectively does the exact same check (it has do, because otherwise you could dead-lock calling `Invoke()` from the UI thread)

Answer (score 1):

> if I remove `ConfigureAwait(false)`, looks to be fine but....program doesn't work correctly

Nevertheless, that is the first step in fixing your problem. By calling `ConfigureAwait(false)`, you are telling the framework to not bother moving back to the UI thread when executing the continuation of your asynchronous operation. Hence you are on the wrong thread when you try to interact with UI objects. Hence the exception.

The next step would be to fix your receiving code. There's nothing in the code that would suggest why you don't seem to receive data. That part should work. But you aren't awaiting the receive operation, which explains why your code goes on to also wait for a new connection. If you don't want that, your code should probably look more like this:

```
private async void ListenForClientsAsync()
{

    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var client = await Server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            if (client.Connected)
            {
                ServerView.UpdateChatBox("Client connected.");
                await ReadStreamAsync(client);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ServerView.UpdateChatBox(e.Message);
    }
}

private async Task ReadStreamAsync(TcpClient client)
{
    NetworkStream streamer = client.GetStream();

    Byte[] buff = new Byte[1024];
    String msg;
    int buffRecived;

    // receive data until connection is closed, i.e. receive completes
    // with 0-byte length.
    while ((buffRecived = await streamer.ReadAsync(buff, 0, buff.Length)) > 0)
    {
        msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buff);
        ServerView.UpdateChatBox(msg);
    }
}
```

Notes:

- I also modified your `ReadStreamAsync()` method so that it will read all the data sent, until the connection is closed.
- If you are reading text, it might make more sense to use line-break delimited text and use `StreamReader` to read the text line-by-line.

Comment: Cross theard exception gone, but application works only for single client connection. If I try to connect another client nothing happens. Server app doesn't see the next connected client, but only the first.

Comment: _"application works only for single client connection"_ -- I read your question to mean that's what you wanted. If you want to be able to handle multiple clients, just remove the `await` from the call to `ReadStreamAsync()`. Then the server will be able to accept more than one client at a time.